# Insert or Update or Skip when adding a record in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE `my_db`.`my_table` (
  `key` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `insert_dt` DATETIME(5) NOT NULL,
  `md5_hash` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  `col0` DATETIME(5) NOT NULL,
  `col1` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `col2` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  `col3` NVARCHAR(50) NULL,
  `col4` NVARCHAR(50) NULL,
  `col5` NVARCHAR(50) NULL,
  `col6` NVARCHAR(50) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`key`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4;
```

- md5_hash is MD5 hash of `col1` through `col6` (I just added it so I don't compare values for all 6 cols, hoping it will make my life easier)
- combination of `col1` + `col2` + `col3` + `col4` should be unique (I can add md5 hash column for these 4 if this will make my life easier)

**I want to:**

- SKIP (do not insert/update) if `md5_hash` exists in the table
- UPDATE record if cobbination of `col1` + `col2` + `col3` + `col4` already exist
- INSERT new if md5_hash does not exists

I currently use following query I found here on SO to SKIP/INSERT, it works great:

```
INSERT INTO `my_db`.`my_table`
  ( `insert_dt`, `md5_hash`, `col0`, `col1`, `col2`, ... )
SELECT * FROM 
  ( SELECT ? as `insert_dt`, ? as `md5_hash`, ? as `col0`, ? as `col1`, ? as `col2`, ... ) AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT `md5_hash` FROM `my_db`.`my_table` WHERE `md5_hash` = ?
) LIMIT 1;
```

It looks like I can do following to INSERT/UPDATE (if I add UNIQUE constraint for `col1` + `col2` + `col3` + `col4`)

```
INSERT INTO `my_db`.`my_table`
  (`insert_dt`, `md5_hash`, `col0`, `col1`, `col2`, ...)
VALUES
  (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ...)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  insert_dt = VALUES(insert_dt),
  md5_hash  = VALUES(md5_hash),
  col0  = VALUES(col0),
  col5  = VALUES(col5),
  col6  = VALUES(col6)
```

But how can I combine the two?

Comment: I think, you need use your own stored procedure.

Comment: There are more ideas here: https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/17/3-ways-to-write-upsert-and-merge-queries-in-mysql/

Comment: Your 3 conditions are meant to be applied one after another, not simultaneously, right? So if the 2nd condition is fulfilled, you update and the list is done? Otherwise they conflict with each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by checking if the `md5-hash` is equal to the current value and then "update" the columns with their current values.

You will need both a unique index on `md5_hash` and `col1, col2, col3, col4`.

You then can use

```
INSERT INTO `my_table`
  (`insert_dt`, `md5_hash`, `col0`, `col1`, `col2`, ...)
VALUES
  (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ...)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  insert_dt = if(md5_hash = VALUES(md5_hash), insert_dt, VALUES(insert_dt)),
  col0 = if(md5_hash = VALUES(md5_hash), col0, VALUES(col0)),
  col5 = if(md5_hash = VALUES(md5_hash), col5, VALUES(col5)),
  col6 = if(md5_hash = VALUES(md5_hash), col6, VALUES(col6)),
  md5_hash = VALUES(md5_hash);
```

If the unique key on `md5_hash` is violated, `md5_hash = VALUES(md5_hash)` and `on duplicate key update` will simply "update" all columns with the their current value, which means it skips the update. Technically, MySQL will even treat this row as not updated at all (e.g. when counting *affected rows* or (not) executing triggers), which means it will actually skip them.

If the unique key on `col1 ... col4` is violated, but not the one on `md5_hash`, which means `md5_hash != VALUES(md5_hash)`, `on duplicate key update` will update the columns with the new values.

If no unique key is violated (so in particular `md5_hash` does not exist yet), it will insert the row as usual.

Please note that `md5_hash` is updated last. This is necessary because MySQL updates columnwise and would use the new column value for successive comparisons (and thus not update these columns).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The problem here, is that `col1 + col2 + col3 + col4` combo is unique, **but it can change** (and should be updated; actually, only `col3` and `col4` can change in my case). I added the UNIQUE indexes as you said, and this script creates a new row when one of the `col1-4` is changed.

Comment: I am not entirely sure if I understand correctly what you are trying to do. It is also not part of your "list". Generally speaking, if `col1`-`col4` are different, how do you know which row MySQL is suppose to replace? A unique key is the only thing that can identify a row in a set. If you insert a different key value, it is a new row. You could add the "key"-column (your primary key) to the `insert` (and then use `if(key = VALUES(key), ...` in addition to `if(md5_hash`), but I am still not sure if that is what you intent to do. Or do you mean an `update` in general, not `on duplicate key`?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think it through enough. Basically I receive sets of data, where there's not a single value is unique. To make things worse, some records can come incomplete, and later get updated with missing values. The good(?) thing is each time I get all records (what is available for the moment. I decided, that `col1 + col2 + (col3 AND/OR col4)` is the minimum I need to save the data to DB. For example, if I only receive `col3`, but not `col4` I still want to save, but if later this record comes with values for both `col3` and `col4` I need to update the record, not insert a new one :-/

Comment: Combination of `col1 + col2 + col3 + col4`, when all values are provided, is unique. But `col1 + col2 + col3` or `col1 + col2 + col4` are not necessarily unique, especially the latter.

Comment: My first idea would be that both `col1,col2,col3` and `col1,col2,col4` are unique and you can apply the same logic. Although I am not sure it is. What happens if you get 1,2, col3=3,col4=null (new row). Then 1,2, col3=null,col4=4 (new row I guess?). Is it possible that you can then can get 1,2,3,4 later? Which row would it be? Or is this technically not possible because of how your data works?

Comment: Ah, I missed your last comment. If I understand that correctly, you are doing something impossible: if col1,col2,col3 are not unique: what should happen if you get 1,2,3,null and then 1,2,3,null again? And if you then get 1,2,3,4, which row is it? Or 1,2,3,4, then 1,2,3,null? Is it the same row or a new one? Or again the example: first1,2,3,null, then 1,2,null,4, then 1,2,3,4?

Comment: You are right. I know what I need to happen in the scenarios you described, but I don't think all of them are possible with the way I'm trying to do things right now. I need to re-think alternatives, maybe I should just delete everything for the date I receive updated records for every time, and just write what I just received. After all it will always be under 1000 records, which, I think, is nothing for SQL... I'm going to accept your answer, though, as it works as advertised, and could be useful to someone else. Thank you very much.